# Find the upper and lower limit of integration (marginal distribution)

Tags: calculus, probability

I have a joint density of two random variables:  $f_{Z,V}(z,v) = \dfrac{1}{\alpha}$, $\alpha\geq1$ .The question is to find the marginal distribution of $Z$. the area of integration is given by: $0< v < 1\enspace$ , $0<z< 1+\alpha$ , $\enspace 0<z-v < \alpha$.

I have three cases:

The first one is when:  $0< z \leq 1$ , then $f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{z} \dfrac{1}{\alpha} dv  = \dfrac{z}{\alpha}$

the second case: $1<z \leq \alpha, \enspace f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{\alpha} dv  = \dfrac{1}{\alpha}$

the last case $\alpha < z < 1 +\alpha$ ,

here is the question: How can i find upper and lower limits in the integration?, in the last case.Can someone show me algebraically , or explain.

Answer (score 1):

When you plot the support of the joint distribution with $z$ on the y-axis and $v$ on the x-axis, you will see that it is a parallelogram with the vertices at $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,\alpha)$ and $(1,1+\alpha)$. Now we attempt to compute the cumulative distribution of $Z$.
$$F_Z(u) = \mathbb{P}(Z\leq u) = \begin{cases}\ \int_0^{u}\int_0^z\frac{1}{\alpha}dvdz \quad 0\leq u\leq 1 \\ \int_0^{1}\int_0^z\frac{1}{\alpha}dvdz + \int_1^{u}\int_0^1\frac{1}{\alpha}dvdz \quad 1\leq u\leq \alpha \\ \int_0^{1}\int_0^z\frac{1}{\alpha}dvdz + \int_1^{\alpha}\int_0^1\frac{1}{\alpha}dvdz + \int_{\alpha}^u\int_{z-\alpha}^1\frac{1}{\alpha}dvdz \quad \alpha\leq u\leq 1+\alpha \end{cases} $$

The probability density of $Z$ follows from differentiating the above expression with respect to $u$.

To answer your question, the limits for your last case are $z-\alpha$ and $1$ as you can see in the last term in the third expression.